# using gcc, g++ outside of xcode on mac

Tags: command-line, xcode

I'd like to spend some time aside from the IDE for a bit and use command line gcc, g++ compilers.

When i use my terminal, they however, can't be found.

How can i install them?

I honestly am surprised why these two don't come standard.

Please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have not already done so, you should install the development tools that come with your Mac in one of the OS discs, which include gcc. So gcc and other such programs are standard, but not installed by default (I suppose the thinking behind this choice is that either one does not need them and won't miss them, or he won't have no trouble in installing them when needed).

Comment: indeed :) I have 2 cds which came with a mac, Applications (contains a bundle of mail,timemachine, spaces, ichat and Finder) and a MacOS Install. I suppose software is on a MACOS install DVD?

Comment: Yes, within the optional installs.

Comment: It seems that Optional Installs do not contains any shell programs at all .. is there specific app/ place i should be looking at?

Comment: Just install the Developer Tools (Xcode) - this installs all the command line tools such as gcc, gdb, etc - download Xcode 3.2.6 from developer.apple.com rather than use an out of date version that came with your Mac